# Java StingIndexoutOfBounds

Tags: java

I keep getting an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String 
>   index out of range: 10
>    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
>    at Field.setLocations(Field.java:175)
>    at Field.(Field.java:39)
>    at SeaBattle.onePlayer(SeaBattle.java:76)
>    at SeaBattle.play(SeaBattle.java:36)
>    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:7)

```
public void setLocations() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> locationToSet = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> temp = null;
        int let, num, incl, incn;
        String alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
        boolean worked;
        for (int i = 0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
            worked = false;
            start: while (!worked) {
                locationToSet.clear();
                worked = true;
                let = rand.nextInt(9);
                num = 1 + rand.nextInt(9);
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    //num even or odd
                    incl = 1;
                    incn = 0;
                } else {
                    incl = 0;
                    incn = 1;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < ships.get(i).getLength(); j++) {
                    String loc = "" + alpha.charAt(let) + num;
                    let += incl;
                    num += incn;

                    for (int t = 0; t < ships.size(); t++) {
                        if (t != i) {
                            temp = ships.get(t).getLocation();
                            if (temp.contains(loc)) {
                                worked = false;
                                continue start;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    locationToSet.add(loc);
                }
                ships.get(i).setLocation(locationToSet);
            }
        }
    }
```

the line 175 is

```
for (int j = 0; j < ships.get(i).getLength(); j++) {
```

I have no idea why I get this error. If I change the `<` in `==` then I don't get the error. But then it won't give my objects their locations.

Comment: I guess line 175 is this one: `String loc = "" + alpha.charAt(let) + num;`

Comment: Not all the code is here it's hard to find the error without all the code for example what is `ships`?  Looks like maybe you are going out of range for `alpha.charAt(let)` you generate a random number for `let` then increase it while iterating over an element in `ships` which has nothing to do with `alpha` I assume?...

Comment: Have you used a debugger an checked each iteration?

Comment: i did but i cannot find the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are already many resources on this in Stack Overflow which can be found with Googling, but I think the larger issue here is you need to **understand how exceptions and errors** are telling you something went wrong, and Java can't do what you told it to do because it's not able to.

Looking at the error you posted. That is a **stacktrace**. You'll see a ton of this in programming, you might hate seeing them but they're your friend, because without them, we can't tell if our program ran properly or not. You can read it from bottom up right after it tells it that an exception of `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurred.

**Here's how to read your error from bottom up:**

> at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:7)

This means that your error started when Java was at this line doing all the function calls. Line 7 of MainClass.java, which jumps to

> at SeaBattle.play(SeaBattle.java:36)

That's line 36 in your SeaBattle java. Which goes to

> at SeaBattle.onePlayer(SeaBattle.java:76)

to

> at Field.(Field.java:39)

to

> at Field.setLocations(Field.java:175)

and finally.

> at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

The last line tells you when you did String.charAt it tried to read from an unknown source, which based on the Exception it gave you, meant that it happened at index 10, possibly meaning your string was only up to 9 characters. (As a guess you probably did a for-loop and tried reading the wrong index)

A good approach is to look at that line and see if you can figure out what's wrong. (Double clicking on the exceptions in IDEs usually brings focus to that point).

If that didn't work..

**Use the debugger**

If you use Eclipse or Netbeans to write java, they all have a debugger that assists you with well, debugging your code. Set a breakpoint at line 7 of MainClass, or any of those lines in that stack trace and run the debugger to step through your code. Here's a [great tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) on how to do that. Manually stepping through your code will let you see exactly what went wrong, that way you can find your problem. Good luck with your homework assignment, this is a good one to learn about for-loops and reading arrays, go ask your TA if you can't figure out the bug, we're more helpful in person.